# Sending form ID to AJAX on button click

Tags: php, ajax

I have a question that's blowing my mind: how do I send a form ID stored in a PHP variable to my AJAX script so the right form gets updated on submit?

My form is a template that loads data from MySQL tables when `$_REQUEST['id']` is set. So, my form could contain different data for different rows.

So, `if (isset($_REQUEST["eid"]) && $_REQUEST["eid"] > 0) { ... fill the form ... }`

The form ID is stored in a PHP variable like this `$form_id = $_REQUEST["eid"];`

I then want to use the button below to update the form if the user changes anything:

```
<button type="submit" id="update" class="form-save-button" onclick="update_form();">UPDATE</button>
```

and the following AJAX sends the data to update.php:

```
function update_form() {
var dataString = form.serialize() + '&page=update';
$.ajax({
url: 'obt_sp_submit.php', // form action url
type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
data: dataString, // serialize form data 
cache: 'false',
beforeSend: function() {
    alert.fadeOut();
    update.html('Updating...'); // change submit button text
},
success: function(response) {
    var response_brought = response.indexOf("completed");
    if(response_brought != -1)
    {
        $('#obt_sp').unbind('submit');
        alert.html(response).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
        $('#obt_sp')[0].reset.click(); // reset form
        update.html('UPDATE'); // reset submit button text
    }
    else
    {
        $('#obt_sp').unbind('submit');
        alert.html(response).fadeIn();
        update.html('UPDATE'); // reset submit button text
    }
},
error: function(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
});
}
```

I'd like to add the form's id to the dataString like this:

```
var dataString = form.serialize() + '&id=form_id' + '&page=update';
```

but I have no idea how. Can someone please help?

Comment: You could put the form id in a hidden input when the page is first created then just get the value of that field when you are submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most practical way as stated above already is to harness the use of the `input type="hidden"` inside a form.
An example of such would be:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id=""myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="eid" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Letting you run something similar to this with your jQuery:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(){
    update_form();
    return false;
});
```

Provided that you send what you need to correctly over the AJAX request (get the input from where you need it etc etc blah blah....)

You could alternatively include it in the data string which; I don't quite see why you would do.. but each to their own.

```
var dataString = form.serialize() + "&eid=SOME_EID_HERE&page=update";
```

Comment: @user3654083 it's a pleasure, hope it all helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the string dynamically with PHP:

```
var dataString = form.serialize() + "&id='<?php echo $REQUEST['eid'] ?>'+&page=update";
```

On the server you can write Php code on the document, and they will be shown as HTML/JS on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a `type=hidden` form field:

`<input type="hidden" name="eid" value="whatever">`